# Mavericks firewall does not keep my choices

Tags: macos, network, python, firewall

I'm on Mavericks and I run a python script to have a minimalist local server.

Anytime I launch the server the firewall popup comes in and asks me "Do you want the application “python2.7” to accept incoming network connections?" I click "Allow".

I have inspected the Firewall Options from "Security and Privacy" and there is an entry "Python" that points to my virtualenv version of python that is marked as "Allow incoming connections".

So everything seems ok but this popup won't go away, it is always there anytime I launch the server.

Might be a problem linked to the different virtualenv installations of python?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the problem is that virtualenv modifies the python binary when it copies it into the environment, invalidating the signature.

Try to follow this and see if it resolves your issue: http://blog.movieos.org/post/63545845092/stop-my-os-x-firewall-complaining-about-a-virtualenv

Comment: Thanks but it says "I can fix this by signing it myself (I have a developer account. Maybe you can use self-signed certificates? Pass)." I can I do this without a dev account?

Comment: Yes you will want to self sign the application.

Comment: Sorry, I meant "how can I do this without a dev account"

Answer (score 0):

You can use a self-signed certificate for this.

Apple's [code signing procedures](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Conceptual/CodeSigningGuide/Procedures/Procedures.html) page explains how to make one.  Look for the part that says "To use the Certificate Assistant to create a self-signed signing identity".